# Redirection Loop Error in Wordpress Website

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have switched to a new website design (to wordpress from static),so in-order to map old pages to new pages i edited the htacess file,But it resulted in a redirection loop and the site was down after days.So i removed the htacess file.How am i supposed to do proper redirection.

Here are the Redirection code contents from the htacess

```
    # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>

    # END WordPress


Redirect /test1.htm http://www.mysite.com/test1

Redirect /test2.htm http://www.mysite.com/test2
```

Answer (score 1):

`Redirect` is a command from a different module than `RewriteRule` is. This will cause problems quite often.

Just do the redirect using `RewriteRule`.

```
#just in case test.html still exists in the filesystem
Options -MultiViews

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^test1\.htm /test1 [L,R=302]
RewriteRule ^test2\.htm /test2 [L,R=302]

# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# END WordPress
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thank you very much.test.html does not exist in the filesystem. If i use this code will the WordPress rewrite rule work fine?

Comment: Yep. Unless WP has a page called `test1.html` :-)

Comment: Got into a problem,i have 2 blocks of same rewrite code  ie:the section  #BEGIN WORDPRESS  --- #END WORDPRESS is repeated 2 times.I have installed BPS Security plugin,where should i insert the rewriterule code you have mentioned

Comment: It is a replacement of all the code you provided above. Just remove the old code you posted, and replace it with the code I provided.